# WPF DataGrid Not Binding to Custom Type Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

I have a type that looks something like this:

```
public struct LogData
{
    public DateTime Time;
    public string Area;
    public string Message;
}
```

In my data context (MVVM) I have an `ObservableCollection<LogData>` exposed as `Log`.

For some reason I can't get any of the field data (Time, Area, Message) to show up. The rows properly appear when they are logged but the values in the data grid are blank.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Log}" SelectionMode="Single" CanUserSortColumns="True">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Time" Binding="{Binding Time}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Area" Binding="{Binding Area}" IsReadOnly="True" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Message" Binding="{Binding Message}" IsReadOnly="True" />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Any idea why the fields appear blank?

Comment: When you run the project, do you get any errors in the Output window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only bind to public properties (see section **Other Characteristics** in [Binding Sources Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx#classes)), e.g.

```
public DateTime Time { get; set; }
```